# GUI buttons are not visible on kindle but visible on Android Devices

Tags: android, android-gui

> i m trying to port my apk from android to kindle fire but i m facing the problem in GUI
>   the kindle device is not showing the GUI buttons which i have created using GUI skin and C# coding lang. where the same apk when i used in my android device it works very fine
>   Can you please help me to figure out whats the problem in it.
>   I have shared the screenshot of my apk
>
> On android device play button is there
>   https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2gE7XRtvFr9Mmdha3FlUEMtUEU/edit?usp=sharing
>
> on kindle its not showing the play button
>   https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2gE7XRtvFr9MEpEdnpyNXpTYVk/edit?usp=sharing
>
> please help
>   thanks in advanced

```
GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(0,0,640,960),mainmenubg); 
mainMenuScreenFlag=true; 
name=screenName.MainMenuscreen; 
MoPubAndroid.hideBanner(true); 
btnStyle.font = heavaltica; 
btnStyle.alignment = TextAnchor.MiddleCenter; 
btnStyle.normal.background = (Texture2D)Resources.Load ("Textures/play"); 
btnStyle.active.background = (Texture2D)Resources.Load ("Textures/play"); 
btnStyle.fontSize = 50; 
if (GUI.Button (new Rect(400,500,191,142)," ",btnStyle)) { 
    name=screenName.otherScreen; PlaySoundFile (tapSound); 
    currentGUIMethod = FirstScreen; 
}
```

Comment: Some code would help.

Comment: GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(0,0,640,960),mainmenubg);
  mainMenuScreenFlag=true;
  name=screenName.MainMenuscreen;
  MoPubAndroid.hideBanner(true);
  btnStyle.font = heavaltica;
  btnStyle.alignment = TextAnchor.MiddleCenter;
  btnStyle.normal.background = (Texture2D)Resources.Load ("Textures/play");
  btnStyle.active.background = (Texture2D)Resources.Load ("Textures/play");
  btnStyle.fontSize = 50;
  
   if (GUI.Button (new Rect(400,500,191,142)," ",btnStyle)) 
   {    
   name=screenName.otherScreen;
   PlaySoundFile (tapSound);
   currentGUIMethod = FirstScreen;
   }

Comment: GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(0,0,640,960),mainmenubg);
  mainMenuScreenFlag=true;
  name=screenName.MainMenuscreen;
  MoPubAndroid.hideBanner(true);
  btnStyle.font = heavaltica;
  btnStyle.alignment = TextAnchor.MiddleCenter;
  btnStyle.normal.background = (Texture2D)Resources.Load ("Textures/play");
  btnStyle.active.background = (Texture2D)Resources.Load ("Textures/play");
  btnStyle.fontSize = 50;
  
   if (GUI.Button (new Rect(400,500,191,142)," ",btnStyle)) 
   {    
   name=screenName.otherScreen;
   PlaySoundFile (tapSound);
   currentGUIMethod = FirstScreen;
   }